# How prevent CSSTidy from removing the *property IE7 Hack? (Or another standalone tool)

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, minify, csstidy

*Bounty: Bounty given to whoever share a standalone command-line CSS minifier for Windows (that is, run just like JSMin and CSSTidy, but actually minifies rather than 'prettify' and remove properties*

Using Visual Studio 2010 `Post-Build Events`, I'm currently working to reduce our CSS/JS framework by merging and minifying the files into `.min` for production when building the solution/project.

For the JS I'm using [`JSmin.exe`](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) while for CSS, [`CSSTidy.exe`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csstidy/)

All okay for JSmin, but CSSTidy is removing all IE7 `*property` hacks and other properties used by display-table.htc (`-dt-display:`). If I use the `--preserve_css=true` setting, it keeps the comments (which I don't want) and the *property have the `*` stripped out (which I want).

*Example:*

```
.row-fluid .span1 {width: 6.382978723%; *width: 6.329787233638298%;}
```

Becomes (note it added linebreak as well):

```
.row-fluid .span1 {
width:6.382979%;
width:6.329787%
}
```

The question made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194307/html-purifier-css-tidy-browser-specific-properties-and-hacks-are-trimmed-ho) is what I'm looking for *BUT* the answer was given for HTML Purifier (which I don't use) instead of a CSSTidy alternative.

**So the questions:**

- Is it possible to make CSSTidy NOT remove the IE7 hacks nor other invalid properties (which I actually use)?
- Is there any other standalone/command-line CSS compressor (specially one which actually *minifies* rather than just tidy it)? (bounty for that)

*Obs.: 
The VS solution is TFS shared, can't make all devs install YUI or whatever other framework which isn't standalone, nor other languages frameworks like Ruby/PHP. Currently the jsmin.exe and csstidy.exe were the best since I just added both to the solution and call them on post-events.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending all Friday searching and not finding a good tool, today I gave a new shot and finally found a tool that minify both CSS and JS.

The name isn't much straightforward, that's why was hard to find: [**Microsoft Ajax Minifier**](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/)

While asks for install, I just copied the folder contents to the project and worked like a charm.

---

**For those who want to use it as Post-Event build:**

Considering you have a .js folder and you want to concatenate and minify all .js files that end with `.debug.js`.

```
type "$(ProjectDir)\Scripts\*.debug.js" | "$(ProjectDir)tools\AjaxMin" -JS -comments:none –global:jQuery,$ -out "$(ProjectDir)\Scripts\myProject.min.js" -clobber
```

- `$(ProjectDir)` is the project folder;
- [`type`](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) is a `cmd.exe` command for displaying the contents of one or more files. So I order to get the contents of all *.debug.js files and leave in the [`STDIN`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdin/);
- Invoke AjaxMin.exe (no need for the `.exe` that I copied to my `\tools\` folder;
- [pass arguments](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command-Line%20Switches) as needed with `-argName:argValue`;
- use `-out` and a pathname with a file that will be outputted;
- add `-clobber` to overwrite if file exists

Now everytime I need to update my css and js files, I re/build the project and voilá, minified CSS and JS.